# Oracle sqlldr - handling null values in input dataset

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-loader

I am working on moving data from MySQL to Oracle.  The MySQL input datasets have been provided via a MySQL data dump.  Null values in the MySQL database were written as "\N" (without the quotes) in the output file.

I am using sqlldr to get the data into Oracle and "\N" values are problematic in columns mapped to NUMBER data type because Oracle thinks they are strings.

How do I tell sqlldr that any \N values in the input dataset should be mapped to Nulls in Oracle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. Note that if you are on unix-based systems, the \N will need to be escaped as follows:

```
...
COLUMN_NM CHAR(4000) NULLIF COLUMN_NM='\\N',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULLIF in the control file.  It will assign null if finds \N in that column. See syntax below.

```
<COLUMN_NUMBER> NULLIF <COLUMN_NUMBER> = '\\N'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This helped get me started in the right direction but didnt work exactly as described.  I did get it working with some slight modifications.

Comment: you can post what worked for you then accept that answer. if you like my answer you can also upvote it.